# Select from table where value can be null

Tags: postgresql, select, null

I try to select from one table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where id=311
         and date BETWEEN '2012-09-01' And '2012-09-09' 
         and col2='a'
         and (col3 ='m' 
              or col3 ='n' 
              or col3=' ' )
ORDER BY date
```

In the table I have situation where col3 has values 'm', 'n' or null, but this select doesn't return rows where col3 has a null value

Comment: 1) date is a reserved word; better not use it as identifier. 2) `AND col3 IN ('a', 'b', 'c')` 3) `...OR col3 IS NULL`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows having column value as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370788/how-to-select-rows-having-column-value-as-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` is something other than `' '` use `col3 is null`

Answer (score 2):

There is three-valued logic in database:
**TRUE, FALSE, NULL(unknown)**

**col3 =''**  is a true condition,

**col3 is null** is an unknown condition.

They are different.

so you must use

> col3 is null

You may reference [Wikipedia's "NULL" entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29).

Answer (score 1):

NULL is not equal to 'm' , 'n' or ' ' . NULL isn't even equal to NULL. Use:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where id=311
         and date BETWEEN '2012-09-01' And '2012-09-09' 
         and col2='a'
         and (col3 ='m' 
              or col3 ='n' 
              or col3 IS NULL)
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
where 
    id=311
    and date BETWEEN '2012-09-01' And '2012-09-09' 
    and col2='a'
    and (
        col3 ='m' 
        or col3 ='n' 
        or col3 is null 
    )
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice trick to avoid the OR list, and to also avoid the `OR IS NULL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE id=311
 AND zdate BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2012-09-09' 
 AND col2='a'
 AND COALESCE(col3, 'm') IN ('m', 'n' )
ORDER BY zdate
   ;
```