# How to select rows having column value as null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Consider following database table:

```
id      |  is_visible
________|_______________
1       |  true
2       |  false
3       |               -- i.e. null
```

I want to select all the rows having is_visible = null. I tried the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE is_visible = null;     -- 0 results
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE is_visible <> true;    -- only fields with false value
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE is_visible <> false;   -- only fields with true
```

I tried it in postgresql and sql server
How to select rows having is_visible = null?

Comment: Is null is better than = 0 or isnull(is_visible,null)=null

Comment: why did you put both sql-server and postgresql -- you can't be using both

Comment: @Hogan I am using postgresql, but when I had problem I tried the same thing in sql-server

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In both Postgres and SQL server,

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE is_visible is null;
```

If you want to select the rows for which column values are not null, then use `is not null` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE is_visible is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, simple answer saved me a lot of time looking into docs.. \n Have a great day sir :)

Answer (score 4):

you can't compare 2 null values in sql server as null is unknown or not available.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196339(v=sql.80).aspx

Use IS NULL operator:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE is_visible IS NULL;  -- only field having null value
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE is_visible IS NOT NULL;    -- fields having not null values
```