# postgresql select return 0 when default value is set to null

Tags: postgresql, null

Have the following table

```
create table t1(
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
 v1 varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  
 v2 text
);
```

executing: `INSERT INTO t1 (v2) VALUES ('aaaa'), ('bbb'), ('ccc');` and then `SELECT * FROM t1` returns as expected:

```
1 |   | aaa
2 |   | bbb
3 |   | ccc
```

When running the following sql I'm expecting to get 1,2,3 and I get 0 rows

`SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE v1=NULL` also tried this `SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE LENGTH(v1)=0`

**HOW can I get the id's**
Cheers

Comment: `v1=NULL` evaluates to `NULL` which is falsy. You will need to use the special syntax `v1 IS NULL`. Or maybe change your default to be the empty string instead if that is what you actually meant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select from table where value can be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385001/select-from-table-where-value-can-be-null) and [How to select rows having column value as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370788/how-to-select-rows-having-column-value-as-null)

Comment: you can use v1 IS NULL OR COALESCE(v1, '') = '' please check url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7137483039b7d27f485e210f1e9f8099

Comment: I changed example code so it would actually work. `()` instead of `{}` for the `CREATE TABLE` and quote `bbb`.  In addition to other comments: `select length(NULL); NULL`, so `LENGTH(v1)=0` is not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In postgres for check value is null or not you should use below keyboard:

- IS NULL
- IS NOT NULL

More details about comparison:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE

```sql
SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE v1 IS NULL
```